# Can't change order of task list fields in newform.aspx or editform.aspx

Tags: list-view

For some reason, when I go into my task list settings, I don't get the "Column Ordering" link that I would expect to see in the column settings of a standard list.

I've already tried disabling and re-enabling "Allow management of content types?" to no avail.

Is this by design? Is there another way I can change the order of the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Content Types, click on **Task**. You will find there at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps:

- Open List Setting Page
- Click on Content Type **`Task`**

[image: Click on Task]

- Here you will find the **`Column Order`**

[image: Column Order]

I hope this will help you.